# Django Models limit ManyToManyField to owner

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to limit the objects that appear on a ManyToManyField based on its owner. 
What would be the correct form of doing it?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AuthorizedIps(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()
    ...

class CustomerSettings(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    authorized_ips = models.ManyToManyField(AuthorizedIps)
    ...
```

Would this be done with the parameter "limit_choices_to="?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing that using [`F() objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model):

Something like:

```
from django.db.models import F
class CustomerSettings(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    authorized_ips = models.ManyToManyField(AuthorizedIps, 
                    limit_choices_to={'owner': F('customersettings__owner')})
```

However, you would have to handle cases when you are creating a object. That time no `owner` will be set, so limit choices will give you empty set.